# Changing UIView color with a UITextField String

Tags: swift, uiview, google-cloud-firestore, uitextfield, uilabel

i have a very simple app that sends Absent/Present to Firestore and the label changes to what is sent to the server.

the UILabel is inside a UIView and i would like to change the color of the view to red when the label displays absent, green when present is displayed.

How can i do this ?

```
@IBOutlet weak var p1ViewColor: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var p1Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var p1ABTF: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var p1PRTF: UITextField!


// fetch data and display it
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    pListener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (docSnapshot, error ) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
        let myData = docSnapshot.data()
        let absent1 = myData?["Absent"] as? String ?? ""
        let present1 = myData?["Present"] as? String ?? ""
        self.p1Label.text = "\(absent1) \(present1)"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply set `p1ViewColor.backgroundColor = UIColor.red` for instance

But first of all you should re-design your **data structure**, that is why you are struggling.

As far as I understand, there can be two states Present and Absent, and this can be achieve with a simple `Bool` in your `docSnapshot`. Imagine there were a simple variable, called `"Present"` which is `true` if present and `false` if absent, your code could look like this :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    pListener = docRef.addSnapshotListener { (docSnapshot, error ) in
        guard let docSnapshot = docSnapshot, docSnapshot.exists else { return }
        guard let myData = docSnapshot.data() else { return }

        let present: Bool = myData["Present"] // "Present" is now a Boolean

        self.p1Label.text = present ? "Present" : "Absent"
        p1ViewColor.backgroundColor = present ? .green : .red
    }
}
```

Prettier, and easier to read.

Comment: oh wow that worked thank you so much, and your right a looks a lot better